# open a specific tab from different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, anchor

Could you help me solve my specific problem? I want to create a link from one page to open another with specific tab active, only with JavaScript.

**---------------------PAGE 1---------------------**

```js
function chooseFloor(evt, oneFloor) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  //Hide all elements with class tabcontent
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('tabcontent');
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++){
    tabcontent[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
 
  //Delete class form all active elements 
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablinks');
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++){
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' active', '');
  }
  
  // show tab
  document.getElementById(oneFloor).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' active'; 
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <a id="tab1" class="tablinks" onclick="chooseFloor(event, 'One')" href="#first" >One</a>
  <a id="tab2" class="tablinks" onclick="chooseFloor(event, 'Two')" href="#second">Two</a>
  <a id="tab3" class="tablinks" onclick="chooseFloor(event, 'Three')" href="#third">Three</a>
  <a id="tab4" class="tablinks" onclick="chooseFloor(event, 'Four')" href="#fourth">Four</a>
</div>

<div class="container">    
  <div id="first" class="tabcontent">Content 1</div>
  <div id="second" class="tabcontent">Content 2</div>
  <div id="Third" class="tabcontent">Content 3</div>
  <div id="fourth" class="tabcontent">Content 4</div>
</div>
```

**---------------------PAGE 2---------------------**

```js
if (location.hash && ['#first', '#second', '#third', '#fourth'].indexOf(location.hash.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
  //function for selecting right tab?
}
```

```html
<div><a href="index.html#first" >Button 1</a></div>
<div><a href="index.html#second" >Button 2</a></div>
<div><a href="index.html#third" >Button 3</a></div>
<div><a href="index.html#fourth" >Button 4</a></div>
```

Comment: whyh do you want to use javascript while you already have a simple solution?

Comment: Because I do not know a simple solution...

Comment: I'm quite confuse here; your page 2 is the solution; if you want page2.html to open on click of first, simple add your href as you did there; href="page2.html#first"

Comment: well, if I click on <div><a href="index.html#first" >Button 1</a></div> I get first page but the tab is not showing up.

Comment: what is showing when you click the link?

Comment: I get the menu buttons from page 1 (no tab opened) and url like this index.html#first / index.html#second ... depending witch button I click. To see the tab I have to click the button from menu.

Comment: what I dont understand is that your buttons are in page 2

Comment: the tabs are working corectly. I want to make mechanism that will make you click for example on button 2 on diffrent page and you will go to page 1 with open tab 2 content

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionstorage to achieve this,use setItem on first page and getitem on target page.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm Probably I should somehow save the information about tab on second page in sessionstorage and read it on first page? Can you tell me little more about this?